# Type of wiring and gauge for pool pump cord replacement

Tags: wiring

I would like to know type and size and gauge of wiring needed to replace an old cord. It is 25' to a GFCI receptacle.

Also, if receptacle is GFCI is it required to have GFCI on cord too?

[image: Intex pool pump]

Comment: Is this the pump you're referencing? https://intexcorp.com/products/above-ground-pools/krystal-clear-filtration-sanitation/sand-filter-pumps/14in-krystal-clear-sand-filter-pump-2800-gal-pump-flow-rate/

Answer (score 2):

If the cut-off chart indicates a maximum of 4.8 Amps, a 16 gauge cord will do fine<sup>1</sup>. It would be good to about 12 Amps. You could to to 14 gauge to mitigate voltage drop a bit, but at 25 feet that's not much of a concern.

Be sure to use a quality end plug so you don't lose power through weak terminals. Actually, I've used commercial extension cords for things like this--just clip off the male end and wire it up.

You generally don't want to stack GFCI protection. That can result in nuisance trips<sup>2</sup> and doesn't significantly increase safety.

<sub>1 Consult any [ampacity chart](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wire-gauges-d_419.html) to verify.</sub>

<sub>2 I've witnessed this myself with a GFCI pond pump cord on stacked GFCI outlets, but it's common knowledge. I removed the downstream GFCI outlet to resolve the problem.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If just replacement of a cord/wire on the pump can use the same size and type, most hardware/electric stores can match it for you.

Only need one GFCI protection device, receptacle or cord, but must use one somewhere on the circuit.

If making a cord or wire circuit yourself(pump did not come with one), you must go by the minimum gauge allowed for the breaker.  14 gauge for 15 amp breaker.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that last statement? Cords are typically sized for the _device_, not the breaker.